# How do I submit the details from a modal window to database in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, forms, modal-dialog

I have made an app in django displaying a form. On filling the fields in the form and hitting the save button, a modal window opens displaying the filled data and asking the user to confirm whether his details are correct. If the user clicks submit, I need to push the data to the database. Here is my code. I'm quite new to Django and have been stuck at this issue for days now. Please help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import Post
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if request.POST.get("submit"):
                post=Post()
                name = request.POST.get('name', '')
                gender = request.POST.get('gender', '')
                dateofbirth = request.POST.get('dateofbirth', '')
                city = request.POST.get('city', '')
                state = request.POST.get('state', '')
                country = request.POST.get('country', '')
                return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form,'successful_submit': True,'name':name,'gender':gender,'dateofbirth':dateofbirth,'city':city,'state':state,'country':country})
            elif request.POST.get("cancel"):
                form=LoginForm()
                return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form=LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
 date_of_birth = models.DateField()
 city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #publication_date = forms.DateTimeInput()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('name', 'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'city', 'state','country',)
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Please Fill in The Details{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Information required</h1>
 </br>
 <h3>Please, use the following form:</h3>
 </br>
 <form method="post">
 {{ form.as_p }}
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div  style="padding-left:50px;">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
 </div>
 </br>
 <div  style="padding-left:50px;">
   <button type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
 </div>
 </form>
{% endblock %}
{% block contentII %}

 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">

               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Please Confirm your Details!!</h5>
               <span class="close">&times;</span>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <table style="width:100%">
                 <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Gender</th>
                 <th>DOB</th>
                 <th>City</th>
                 <th>State</th>
                 <th>Country</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <td> {{name}}</td>
                 <td> {{gender}}</td>
                 <td> {{dateofbirth}}</td>
                 <td> {{city}}</td>
                 <td> {{state}}</td>
                 <td> {{country}}</td>
                 </tr>
               </table>
             </div>

             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button id="can" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
               <input id="tag-form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
             </div>

           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

  {% if successful_submit %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
    });
  </script>
  {% endif %}
  <script>

var modal = document.getElementById("exampleModal");
var can = document.getElementById("can");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
can.onclick = function() {
  $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
}
span.onclick = function() {
  $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}

</script>

  </br>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: its not about Django. Its about Javascript on your page. JS can get data from your form and fill your modal with data.

Comment: @VitAmin modal is filled with data. what I want is to submit this data to the database. Can You please help me out. Thanks